# Updating ViewPager Adapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using tabLayout which is attached with the viewPager. I have implemented viewPager Adapter using FragmentStatePager adapter, because the tabLayout list is big.

ViewPager creates a new instance of each fragment, and inside the fragment, i am using recyclerView to the data.

Now, before initiating the viewPager i am making a call to the server, and in success response, i am initiating viewPager for the first time. Then viewPager calls its getItem() callback, where it gets the data for the first position initialises the fragment and it's recyclerView.

It also call getItem() for the next position as i have set the offScreenLimit() to 2, which is fine and working well.

The problem is when it calls getItem() and creates the fragment, at that time, i am checking if i have the data, if not, then i am making a callback to get data from server.

And if user visits that position, i want to updated the fragment recyclerView.

Here, i have passed the reference of the main object in the fragment, so on success of request, it updates the main object, and the updated object will be present inside the fragment list.

Since, it's an asynchronous call, i want to show a loader and then update the fragment.

Here is where my problem lies. I am not able to update the fragment recyclerView. It's updating but taking time.

I had tried using return **POSITION_NONE** which worked fine, but it's not a good approach as it creates a new fragment every time.

This is my viewPagerAdapter.

```
public class ShowTimeViewPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = ShowTimeViewPageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mDateStringList;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private IShowTimeActivity mIShowTimeActivity;

    private List<String> mDateCodes;
    private LinkedHashMap<String, List<Venue>> mVenueHashMap;

    public ShowTimeViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, IShowTimeActivity showTimeActivity, List<String> createdDates, List<String> dateCodes, LinkedHashMap<String, List<Venue>> venueHashMap) {
        super(fm);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mIShowTimeActivity = showTimeActivity;
        this.fragmentManager = fm;
        this.mDateCodes = dateCodes;
        this.mVenueHashMap = venueHashMap;
        this.mDateStringList = createdDates;
    }

    private String getDateCode(int pos) {
        String dateCode = null;
        try {
            dateCode = mDateCodes.get(pos);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Index out of bound");
        }
        return dateCode;
    }

    private List<Venue> getVenuesList(String dateCode) {
        return mVenueHashMap.get(dateCode);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (getDateCode(position) != null) {
            if (getVenuesList(getDateCode(position)) == null) {
                if(position!=0){
                    mIShowTimeActivity.requestForTheVenueListByDateCode(getDateCode(position), position);
                }
            }
        }
        ShowTimeFragment showTimeFragment = ShowTimeFragment.newInstance(mDateStringList.get(position).split(";")[2]);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(showTimeFragment,""+position);
        return showTimeFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDateStringList.size();
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        String[] dateStr = mDateStringList.get(position).split(";");
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View tabView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.show_time_tab_layout, null, false);
        TextViewRoboto day = (TextViewRoboto) tabView.findViewById(R.id.show_time_tab_day);
        TextViewRoboto date = (TextViewRoboto) tabView.findViewById(R.id.show_time_tab_date);
        day.setText(dateStr[0]);
        date.setText(dateStr[1]);
        return tabView;
    }

}
```

And this is the Fragment.

```
public class ShowTimeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Bind(R.id.show_time_fragment_recycler_view)        RecyclerView mShowTimeRecyclerView;
    @Bind(R.id.show_time_fragment_no_data_text_view)    TextViewRoboto mShowTimeNoDataTextView;

    private static LinkedHashMap<String, List<Venue>> mVenueList = ShowTimeActivity.mVenueHashMap;

    private ShowTimeRecyclerViewAdapter mShowTimeRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private static final String KEY_CODE = "date_key";

    public ShowTimeFragment() {
    }

    public static ShowTimeFragment newInstance(String dateCode) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(KEY_CODE, dateCode);
        ShowTimeFragment showTimeFragment = new ShowTimeFragment();
        showTimeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return showTimeFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_time_fragment, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);


        String code = getArguments().getString(KEY_CODE);

        List<Venue> venueList = mVenueList.get(code);

        if (venueList != null && venueList.size() > 0) {
            mShowTimeRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mShowTimeNoDataTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mShowTimeRecyclerViewAdapter = new ShowTimeRecyclerViewAdapter(venueList, getContext());
            mShowTimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mShowTimeRecyclerViewAdapter);

            CustomLinearLayoutManager cl = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1, false);
            mShowTimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(cl);

            RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener disabler = new RecyclerViewDisabler();
            mShowTimeRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(disabler);        // disables scrolling
        } else {
            mShowTimeNoDataTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mShowTimeRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mShowTimeNoDataTextView.setText("NO Data Available");
        }

        return view;
    }

    public class RecyclerViewDisabler implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }

    protected void addFragment(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag).disallowAddToBackStack().commit();
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

    }
}
```

In the above fragment

```
private static LinkedHashMap<String, List<Venue>> mVenueList = ShowTimeActivity.mVenueHashMap;
```

this hashMap is the reference to the original hashMap, which is updated on each request.

Any kind of help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The main object list of data is in the fragment, it's just a reference of the original object which is always modified for each new request. So, my fragment checks if that data is there for that pos,  and gives it to the recyclervVew adapter. It's working fine for the position because, before initiating itself, i am giving the object with first location. In other scenarios, when i got to the tab, it doesn't update, the list, but if go to other tabs and comes back it does.

Comment: @Daniel I have updated my question, and added the code snippet.